# objMailItem.Attachments.add and %temp% location

Tags: vbscript, outlook

How do I add an attachment in Outlook from Windows' %temp% folder?

Somewhere in the script I have:

```
Dim tempfolder
Set tempfolder = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(TemporaryFolder)
```

(...)

```
objMailItem.Attachments.add tempfolder & "\file.zip"
```

but it does not work. Any ideas?
Thanks a million.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to put in value 2 not the constant temporaryfolder. Remember VBS is late bound so their are no constants from objects. You have to look it up and put the value in.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand. Can you explain? Thanks.

Comment: Set tempfolder = objFSO.GetSpecialFolder(2)